# Openstack with Microstack, I can't make empty Volume

Tags: openstack, microstack

I'm a beginner at Openstack. I have an Ubuntu Server on a VM and on it, I installed Openstack with Microstack. Everything looks fine but I cannot make a Volume. It gives me this error:

```
schedule allocate volume: Could not find any available weighted backend.
```

[image]

I looked up everywhere for a solution but can't understand what is the issue.

Comment: Did you deploy cinder service? What does `openstack volume service list` show you?

Comment: @eblock It has an ID, the name of my volume, status Error, and attached to none

Comment: Then check the cinder logs for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

microstack disabled cinder blockstorage service, and you should enable it during initializing. Further more, microstack can only use loop device file as backend.

```
sudo microstack init --auto --control \
 --setup-loop-based-cinder-lvm-backend \
 --loop-device-file-size 50
```